# No value at JSON path $[0].nom?

Tags: json, spring-boot, junit, mockito, hamcrest

I'm currently developping a rest api web service and i have to test them using  unit testing, so i cannot figure out how to test the RESTFul API with Spring using Mockito and Junit, first of all i have preapared the class in which i created two method with @Before and @Test, when i turned in debugging mode the method in the the controle "getEmployeDTOList" always return null therefore the console show me Exception NullPointerException.

the class EmployeControllerTest:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class EmployeControllerTest {

    private MockMvc mockMvc;
    @InjectMocks
    private EmployeController employeController ; 
    @Mock
    private EmployeService employeService ;
    @Mock
     IConverter converterDto ; 

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception{
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        mockMvc=MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(employeController).build();
    }
    @Test
    public void testgetAllEmployee() throws Exception{
        List<Employe> employes= Arrays.asList(

                new Employe("BOUROUNIA", "HICHEM", "h.bourounia", "9dfd1be37de137f146ca990310a1483c",true)
                ,new Employe("BRADAI", "ALI", "a.bradai", "830ddf1b7e8e34261f49d20e5e549338",true) );
            when(employeService.findAll()).thenReturn(employes);
            mockMvc.perform(get("/employe/dto"))
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.content().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE))
            .andExpect(jsonPath("$", hasSize(2)))
         .andExpect(jsonPath("$[0].nom", is("BOUROUNIA")))
         .andExpect(jsonPath("$[0].prenom", is("HICHEM")))
         .andExpect(jsonPath("$[0].login", is("h.bourounia")))
         .andExpect(jsonPath("$[0].mp", is("9dfd1be37de137f146ca990310a1483c")))
         .andExpect(jsonPath("$[0].actif", is(true)))
         .andExpect(jsonPath("$[1].nom", is("BRADAI")))
         .andExpect(jsonPath("$[1].prenom", is("ALI")))
         .andExpect(jsonPath("$[1].login", is("a.bradai")))
         .andExpect(jsonPath("$[1].mp", is("830ddf1b7e8e34261f49d20e5e549338")))
         .andExpect(jsonPath("$[1].actif", is(true))).andReturn().getResponse().getContentAsString();

        verify(employeService,times(1)).findAll();
        verifyNoMoreInteractions(employeService);        
}
    }
```

this is Employecontroller:

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*", allowedHeaders = "*")
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/employe")
public class EmployeController {
@GetMapping("/dto")
public List<EmployeDTO > getEmployeDTOList(){
    try {
        List<Employe> listemp=employeService.findAll();


        return  listemp.stream()
            .filter(Objects::nonNull)
            .map(emp ->converterDTO.convertToDto(emp))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());


    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
} 
}
```

error that i got:

> java.lang.AssertionError: No value at JSON path "$[0].id":
>   com.jayway.jsonpath.PathNotFoundException: Expected to find an object
>   with property ['id'] in path $[0] but found 'null'. This is not a json
>   object according to the
>   JsonProvider:'com.jayway.jsonpath.spi.json.JsonSmartJsonProvider'

Answer (score 0):

I am also new to rest api web service and unit testing. From my experience shouldn't the jsonPath be `jsonPath("$.employes[0].mp")` rather than `jsonPath("$[0].mp").`
The reasoning is that since it is returning a ArrayList you have to indicate the object that is holding the data.
The syntax that I use is `$.ArrayListName[elementPosition].columnName`.